# HTML5 Gradient: changing color of gradient changes color of triangle on a canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am taking an [HTML5 Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kDyJN7qQETA) that is pretty awesome. I got to the radial gradient section of the canvas section of the video, which is about 59 min 44 sec in. I am having an issue that I can't identify where when I change the color of a gradient in the radial gradient, it adds a fill to the triangle. [click here for a screenshot of the output](http://learn.ryanschostag.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/stack_output_gradient_adds_solid_color_to_another_shape.png).

The code for the canvas is on a JS file, and here is the function snippet with the triangle and radial gradient:

```
function init(){
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    if(canvas.getContext){
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        // rectangles
        ctx.fillStyle = "#FAEBD7";
        ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);

        // triangle
        ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(350,200);
        ctx.lineTo(400,50);
        ctx.lineTo(450,200);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fill();

        // add stroke to triangle
        ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(350,200);
        ctx.lineTo(400,50);
        ctx.lineTo(450,200);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.stroke();

        // radial gradient
        var radGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(275,250,5,290,260,100);
        radGrad.addColorStop(0,"red");
        radGrad.addColorStop(1,"pink");
        ctx.fillStyle=radGrad;
        ctx.arc(250,200,25,0,Math.PI*2,true);
        ctx.fill(); 
    }
}

onload = init;
```

When I removed the radial gradient, the triangle goes back to what it was originally. [here is a screenshot or the correct looking triangle](http://learn.ryanschostag.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/stack_output_correct_looking_triangle.png).

I tried messing with the parameters of `var radGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(275,250,5,290,260,100)`, looking for perhaps matching numbers and changing them, seeking conflicts with the radial gradient and the triangle, but have no success.

Thank you!

Please help me so I can have the radial gradient on the page and the correct looking triangle.

Comment: I have made some changes here to do with your gradient positioning, https://jsfiddle.net/1gfxyz0m/ however I'm a bit unsure what you're asking if it's the position of the gradient it should be the top most effect. also this is worth a read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/createRadialGradient

Comment: @JonathanNewton In the screenshots I posted, it shows the triangle a different style than the circle. The circle is supposed to have its own gradient. No matter what I do to the circle, the triangle gets one of the colors. I don't understand why. Even your fillStyle for the triangle is 'yellow' but it is still the same exact gradient as the circle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a look at he triangle and the `arc` and the difference was the `ctx.beginPath();` and `ctx.closePath();`, and it stopped my second `radGrad.addColorStop(1,"pink")` or whatever color I added from changing the color of the triangle. You can see the new code below and a [screenshot here](http://learn.ryanschostag.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/stack_correct_output.png).

```
    var radGrad = ctx.createRadialGradient(275,250,5,290,260,100);
    radGrad.addColorStop(0,"red");
    radGrad.addColorStop(1,"pink");
    ctx.fillStyle=radGrad;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(250,200,25,0,Math.PI*2,true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
```

Comment: closePath is useless for you arc

Comment: @Kaiido yes, but it fixed the problem I was having.

Comment: Nope beginPath did, closePath is useless here.

Comment: @Kaiido Okay thank you. I get it, beginPath() started the new path, where without it, I was still editing the previous graphic. Right?

Comment: yes that's it. `closePath()` is just a `lineTo(first_declared_point_of_the_path_or_last_moved_point)`